# Can we coat brass with nickel by peen (mechanical) plating?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical

Is it possible to plate brass conductor with aluminum by peen plating?

Comment: A good question for a google search.

Comment: @SolarMike I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Nickel or aluminum ? , but I never encountered it for either : except "explosion bonding". Components are at ambient temperature and are pushed together VERY forcefully Basically done mostly with flat plate.

Comment: Thank you, but do you think I can do this for pins of an electrical plug??